# Button should stay focused after modal opens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am in very difficult struggle with one effect, which I believe is wanted in Bootstrap, but I want to escape. I have button:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Video<i class="pe-7s-angle-right pe-2x pe-va" style="line-height: 0.3;"></i></a>
```

Which opens modal window with some video:

```
<div class="modal fade video-lightbox in" id="video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 442px;"></div>
```

So when I open the modal, my button loses focus (and the corresponding styling) automatically. 
I want my button to be in focus the whole time the modal is open.

I tried finding the offender in bootstrap.js, but I don't know how to locate it, to be honest...

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible but why don't you just set up a predefined class which copies the 'focus' styling? You could then disable it on modal hide.

Comment: Adding `tabindex="-1"` to the video might prevent it from automatically getting focus when playing. Emphasis on ***might***. But really, focus is not something you should rely on when styling something, especially a button. It tends to be in the gray area left for browsers to handle, and often opinionated among users. If you need control over that button's styling, take @Aer0's advice: use a class.

Comment: Actually, that makes total sense. I figured bootstrap applies and later removes their .focus class. But this is not the case! I've solved my problem by adding the .focus class to my button through JS.